# how to get JMX data from tomcat webapps behind load balancer

Tags: tomcat, jmx

I have a java webapp which is deployed on multiple tomcat servers behind load balancer ...  Is there any way to get JMX data from each of webapp instance??  I wonder if there is any tool for this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Only the load balancer's ip is public and none of the tomcat machines are known to the public.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jolokia](http://jolokia.org) or [hawtio](http://hawt.io) for this purpose. Jolokia or hawtio is nothing but another web application under tomcat server converting the JMX data into HTTP or HTTPS. That way the JMX data becomes available over standard HTTP/HTTPS port and can be accessed even in the presence of load balancer.

Hawtio internally uses Jolokia itself, but provides an UI. However that is not the only difference.